# How do I copy shape tool nodes to another object?

Tags: shapes, corel-draw

I'm trying to copy the shape tool I used to reshape an object and use it on another object.

e.g.: I have a square object then I used shape tool to reshape it
into a circle now I want to get another whatever shape it is and also reshape
it into a circle exactly as what I did to the first object.

l already tried just copying the nodes but I copy the whole object itself not just the nodes. Is this possible? Or is there any software I can do this?

Comment: Are you trying to copy nodes from on object to another? or trying to apply the same node transformations you did on one object to another?

Comment: @Samg im trying to apply the same node transformation to another object